# app not installed as package appears to be invalid

Tags: package

When I debug a apk and trying to install real device of emulator then show the message "**app not installed as package appears to be invalid**"
I already do things:

1. Clean build
2. Invalidate Caches(Invalidate and Restart)
3. Uninstall old app from android (mobile)
4. added  **android:installLocation="internalOnly"** **debuggable= true**

But has still this problems.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ysbb.png

I expect a solution that, the apk will successfully installed any device.